# getType().getValue() is not working (Google Form)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I was trying to get the string of the item type from one of the Google Form items but it won't work.

```js
// Get the item type.
function test1() {
  // Get the form.
  const testForm8 = FormApp.openById('spreadsheetId');
  // Get the item array.
  const itemArray = testForm8.getItems();
  // Get the first item.
  const item = itemArray[0];
  // Get the item type.
  const itemType = item.getType();
  // Get the item type as a string.
  // !!!getValue is not working!!!
  const itemTypeString = itemType.getValue();
  console.log(itemTypeString);
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work. Please be precise, read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I get that you can't access [`Item.getType()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#gettype) results. If I understood correctly, then you only need a minor change in the code to proceed. As it is explained on the linked docs, `getType()` returns an [`ItemType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-type) enum. If you want to log its value, you can do it directly with a code similar to this one:

```js
function test1() {
  const testForm8 = FormApp.openById(
    '12Fnwvg5ILGJSOPkQaDSdVikKWlBrheiHHQqxM8rLTW4');
  const itemArray = testForm8.getItems();
  const item = itemArray[0];
  const itemType = item.getType();
  console.log(itemType);
}
```

Please ask me any question if you have doubts about this approach.

Comment: Hello, Jacques. Thank you for your reply. You encourage me to keep working. So, I finally could get the string. I used toString instead of getValue. To get the value from the enum Thank you! '

Answer (score 0):

This one worked.

```js
// Get the item type.
function test1() {
  // Get the form.
  const testForm8 = FormApp.openById('12Fnwvg5ILGJSOPkQaDSdVikKWlBrheiHHQqxM8rLTW4');
  // Get the item array.
  const itemArray = testForm8.getItems();
  // Get the first item.
  const item = itemArray[0];
  // Get the item type.
  const itemType = item.getType();
  // Get the item type as a string.
  // !!!getValue is not working!!!
  const itemTypeString = itemType.toString();
  console.log(itemTypeString);
}
```